# How to create many roles at once? (asp.net core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, roles

I'm trying to develop an algorithm that creates many roles in the beginning of the first use of a project.
it needs "async await" task like the following.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> LoginAsync()
    {
        int rolesCount = roleManager.Roles.Count();
        string[] roles = { "Teacher", "Student" };
        var role = new IdentityRole();

        if (rolesCount == 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < roles.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(roles[i]))
                {
                    role.Name = roles[i];
                    await roleManager.CreateAsync(role);
                }
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

it displays this error

> SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_AspNetRoles'.
> Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.AspNetRoles'. The duplicate
> key value is (f32270bc-a54a-42a4-8968-9e402ddaeb0e).
> The statement has been terminated.

the problem that the primary key of the first role "Teacher" not changed during the loop for the second role "Student". So a constraint conflict appears.

So, how to create many roles at once in an "async await" task?

Comment: I think it's because of this: 
`if (rolesCount == 0)`
You are doing your 'for' loop when 'rolesCount' equal to 0 and you have not any roles to check lenght of them.

Comment: @Arash I need to create roles when there is no role found, so nothing wrong with if.

Comment: If my answer is helpful,can you mark it?Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change your code like this:

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> LoginAsync()
    {
        int rolesCount = roleManager.Roles.Count();
        string[] roles = { "Teacher", "Student" };
        

        if (rolesCount == 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < roles.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(roles[i]))
                {
                    var role = new IdentityRole();
                    role.Name = roles[i];
                    await roleManager.CreateAsync(role);
                }
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

When you use `var role = new IdentityRole();`It will create an Id for role.In your code,you put the code outside for loop,so when you run `await roleManager.CreateAsync(role);`,the role.Id will be the same.You only change the name of role.

Here is a test:
[image]